# replace homoglyph in a php string

Tags: php, spam-prevention, homoglyph

I'm working on an anti-spam bot which struggle to decode homoglyphes.

Here is a sample message:

```
ɪ ᴄᴀɴ'ᴛ ꜱᴛᴏᴘ ꜱʜᴀʀɪɴɢ ᴛʜᴇ ɢᴏᴏᴅ ɴᴇᴡꜱ ᴀʙᴏᴜᴛ ꜰᴏʀᴇx ᴍᴀʀᴋᴇᴛ ᴄᴏᴍᴘᴀɴʏ.
ᴡʜᴇɴ ɪ ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ ʜᴇᴀʀᴅ ɪᴛ, ɪ ᴡᴀꜱ ᴀꜰʀᴀɪᴅ ʙᴜᴛ ʟᴀᴛᴇʀ ꜱᴜᴍᴍᴏɴᴇᴅ ᴄᴏᴜʀᴀɢᴇ ᴀɴᴅ ᴍᴀᴅᴇ ᴀ ᴍᴏᴠᴇ ᴡɪᴛʜ $200
ɪ ꜱᴛɪʟʟ ᴄᴀɴ'ᴛ ʙᴇʟɪᴇᴠᴇ ᴛʜᴇ ᴘʟᴀᴛꜰᴏʀᴍ ɪꜱ ꜱo ʀᴇᴀʟ ᴜɴᴛɪʟ ɪ ʀᴇᴄᴇɪᴠᴇᴅ $3,100 IN 48HOURS of trade ᴀꜱ ᴍʏ ᴘʀᴏꜰɪᴛ
ᴛʜɪꜱ ɪꜱ ʏᴏᴜʀ ᴍᴏᴍᴇɴᴛ ᴏꜰ ʀᴇᴅᴇᴍᴘᴛɪᴏɴ ᴊᴜꜱᴛ ᴏɴᴇ ᴄʟɪᴄᴋ ᴀᴡᴀʏ ꜰʀᴏᴍ ɢʀᴇᴀᴛɴᴇꜱꜱ, ᴍᴀᴋᴇ ᴀ ᴍᴏᴠᴇ ɴᴏᴡ ʟᴇᴛ ʜɪꜱᴛᴏʀʏ ʙᴇ ᴍᴀᴅᴇ
ʜᴇʀᴇ ɪꜱ ᴛʜᴇ ʟɪɴᴋ ʙᴇʟᴏᴡ
```

I tried several solutions, but none of them seems to do the job correctly.
Actually I have this code:

```
<?php
$text = "ɪ ᴄᴀɴ'ᴛ ꜱᴛᴏᴘ ꜱʜᴀʀɪɴɢ ᴛʜᴇ ɢᴏᴏᴅ ɴᴇᴡꜱ ᴀʙᴏᴜᴛ ꜰᴏʀᴇx ᴍᴀʀᴋᴇᴛ ᴄᴏᴍᴘᴀɴʏ.
ᴡʜᴇɴ ɪ ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ ʜᴇᴀʀᴅ ɪᴛ, ɪ ᴡᴀꜱ ᴀꜰʀᴀɪᴅ ʙᴜᴛ ʟᴀᴛᴇʀ ꜱᴜᴍᴍᴏɴᴇᴅ ᴄᴏᴜʀᴀɢᴇ ᴀɴᴅ ᴍᴀᴅᴇ ᴀ ᴍᴏᴠᴇ ᴡɪᴛʜ $200
ɪ ꜱᴛɪʟʟ ᴄᴀɴ'ᴛ ʙᴇʟɪᴇᴠᴇ ᴛʜᴇ ᴘʟᴀᴛꜰᴏʀᴍ ɪꜱ ꜱo ʀᴇᴀʟ ᴜɴᴛɪʟ ɪ ʀᴇᴄᴇɪᴠᴇᴅ $3,100 IN 48HOURS of trade ᴀꜱ ᴍʏ ᴘʀᴏꜰɪᴛ
ᴛʜɪꜱ ɪꜱ ʏᴏᴜʀ ᴍᴏᴍᴇɴᴛ ᴏꜰ ʀᴇᴅᴇᴍᴘᴛɪᴏɴ ᴊᴜꜱᴛ ᴏɴᴇ ᴄʟɪᴄᴋ ᴀᴡᴀʏ ꜰʀᴏᴍ ɢʀᴇᴀᴛɴᴇꜱꜱ, ᴍᴀᴋᴇ ᴀ ᴍᴏᴠᴇ ɴᴏᴡ ʟᴇᴛ ʜɪꜱᴛᴏʀʏ ʙᴇ ᴍᴀᴅᴇ
ʜᴇʀᴇ ɪꜱ ᴛʜᴇ ʟɪɴᴋ ʙᴇʟᴏᴡ
";



$homoglyphes = array(
    " " => "\s",
    "A" => "AꭺᗅꓮᎪÅÁÀᴀÂÃАＡÄΑ",
    "B" => "ᗷßꞴＢΒвᛒꓐВᏼℬBβʙᏴ",
    "C" => "ⲤＣℭꓚᏟℂCⅭСϹ",
    "D" => "ᗞĐᗪĎꓓDⅅⅮᴅＤᎠꭰ",
    "E" => "ÈĚÉᴇЕĒℰ⋿ĔΕËꭼĖEＥĘꓰÊᎬⴹ",
    "F" => "FꓝᖴꞘℱＦϜ",
    "G" => "ＧԍɢᏀնꮐᏻꓖԌGᏳ",
    "H" => "ℍⲎꓧһнᎻℋꮋHᕼʜΗＨНℌ",
    "I" => "ιⅠiᛁꭵاӏΙІlᎥ˛⍳IιіꙇⅰɪīｉͺɩℹⅈıＩ",
    "J" => "ᎫᴊＪͿյJꭻЈᒍꓙꞲ",
    "K" => "КᛕꓗKKⲔᏦΚＫ",
    "L" => "ιＬⳐLlⳑʟⅬꓡᏞᒪℒꮮⅼ",
    "M" => "ᎷℳΜϺⅯᗰМMꓟᛖⲘＭ",
    "N" => "ＮℕⲚNɴꓠΝ",
    "O" => "οΟｏՕО0ＯoOо",
    "P" => "ᏢꮲℙРᑭΡꓑᴩⲢᴘPＰ",
    "Q" => "QℚႳႭⵕＱ",
    "R" => "ꭱＲℝꮢᖇℛᚱℜƦRꓣᎡᏒʀ",
    "S" => "ᏕႽЅＳSꓢsｓᏚՏѕ",
    "T" => "⟙ᎢΤтᴛⲦτꭲＴT⊤Тꓔ",
    "U" => "ՍUＵԱ⋃uμυሀ∪ꓴᑌ",
    "V" => "ꓦᏙѴⅤＶꛟV۷٧ⴸᐯ",
    "W" => "ԜＷｗꓪWwᏔᎳ",
    "X" => "ｘꞳＸꓫⅩΧ╳ᚷXⲬⵝχХ᙭",
    "Y" => "ᎩʏｙҮϒγᎽꓬyуＹYУⲨΥ",
    "Z" => "ℨℤᏃΖꓜＺZ",
    "a" => "ã⍺αǎɑâаａáạäàăåȧaą",
    "b" => "ЬḇƅᏏᖯḅdḃlɓƄｂbʙ",
    "c" => "ᴄⲥꮯᏟϲсⅭcⅽｃ",
    "d" => "ꓒԁᏧɗḏďｄdɖlᑯⅾḓժḑḋđcḍbⅆ",
    "e" => "ꬲ℮êėⅇȩҽēḛĕɇẹℯęéeëèеěcｅ",
    "f" => "ꞙƒｆẝfքꬵſϝḟꜰ",
    "g" => "ɡᶃɢǧgqģｇնցġℊĝǥƍğǵ",
    "h" => "ħȟհᏂⱨẖһlḥḩℎɦｈhĥḧḣḫ",
    "i" => "ιⅠiᛁɨꭵاӏ1lȋᎥ˛⍳ιіꙇⅰɪỉīĭｉͺíɩℹịǐïⅈıＩì",
    "j" => "jϳյɉʝјⅉｊ",
    "k" => "ḳḵｋκⱪkķᴋ",
    "m" => "ᴍｍmṁⅿḿṃɱrn",
    "n" => "ｎñrռmꞑṅńņǹɴnṇňṉո",
    "o" => "ᴏ",
    "p" => "ƥṗᏢṕｐρ⍴ƿϱⲣＰpр",
    "q" => "gգｑʠqႭԛႳզ",
    "r" => "ṛrᴦꭈɼṙṟꭇȑԻгɾŕɍȓⲅŗｒřʀɽꮁ",
    "s" => "ꜱႽЅṣƽŝṡＳʂśSsｓᏚѕꮪșšՏ",
    "t" => "ṫᎢțƫτţｔṭtŧ",
    "u" => "ůūǔùUꭎｕՍＵųűưꞟʉսûԱú⋃uũȗụüυμʋŭȕᴜꭒ",
    "v" => "⋁ѵѴｖvⱱνטⱴᴠ∨ⅴṽꮩṿᶌ",
    "w" => "ẅẘɯＷvｗẇẁẉWwẃԝꮃաⱳᎳŵᴡѡ",
    "x" => "ｘ⤬ᕽⅩᕁ᙮х×⤫ⅹχx⨯",
    "y" => "ʏɣｙҮŷγƴỿℽɏꭚẏყỵүȳyýÿуＹYᶌΥ",
    "z" => "ꮓźｚᏃʐƶżⱬẕᴢẓz"
);

foreach ($homoglyphes as $letter=>$glyphes) {
    $tab = mb_str_split($glyphes);
    $text = str_replace($tab, $letter, $text);
}
echo $text;
```

?>

The output is buggy:

```
I dAN'T sToP sHARING THE GooD NEws ABouT foREx nARkET donPANy.
wHEN I fIRsT HEARD IT, I wAs AfRAID BuT LATER sunnoNED douRAGE AND nADE A nowE wITH $2OO
I sTILL dAN'T BELIEwE THE PLATfoRn Is sO REAL uNTIL I REdEIwED $3,iOO IN 48HOuRs Of tnade As ny PRofIT
THIs Is youR nonENT of REDEnPTIoN JusT oNE dLIdk AwAy fRon GREATNEss, nAkE A nowE Now LET HIsToRy BE nADE
HERE Is THE LINk BELow
```

I cannot figure out why.
The only way I could get a correct result is by using TESSERACT-OCR (optical character recognition), but I then need to create an image with the text which is not an option for a  bot which process hundreds of messages per seconds.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if your normalising it back to printable chars, it's not really anti-spam

Comment: I need to normalize it so i can make some regex check on it.
I'm open to any other solution, have you an idea ?

Comment: It appears as though in both the lowercase d and e collections there are characters that are seen as the letter c.

Comment: do the other way around, split the string then find the chars in the set then replace that individual char, https://3v4l.org/ucU4N what's happening is str_replace is string wide with precedence so take `n` for example in `tnade`, you have `r` in `R` and `m`, it hits `n` first so `r` gets replaced with `n`, same with all the other borked chars.. once you replace all the chars your need lowercase it all, then you can do your anti-spam